# Convergence of $\displaystyle\int_0^1(1-t)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(\int_{t^2}^1r^{-2}\log^{-\alpha}\frac{2}{1-r^2}dr\right)^\frac{1}{2}dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Find all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ for which there exists a positive constant $C_\alpha$ so that $$\displaystyle\int_0^1(1-t)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(\int_{t^2}^1r^{-2}\log^{-\alpha}\frac{2}{1-r^2}dr\right)^\frac{1}{2}dt\leq C_\alpha<\infty.$$

I was trying to find some estimate for the inner integral and then for the integral above, but without success. Any advise or solution will be really helpful.